# Laravel Eloquent Json Column Update Overwrites Old Data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two step registration on my website, and I'm trying to update user information data which I have in the data column. The first step is the username and last name and on second step I'm trying to insert additional data into my JSON column. This is my step two update:

```
$user->update([
       'data' => [
           'add_info' => json_encode($new_array_of_data)
    ]);
```

But this overwrites old data which I inserted on step one.

Comment: I think you should give us more code from your work

Comment: @Misa How can i insert my new data in Json Column without overwrite old data in this column

Answer (score 1):

To update `json` type column, you need to use the following syntax:

```
$user->update(['data->add_info' => $your_data]);
```

According to: [New JSON-column where() and update() syntax in Laravel 5.3](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: this way works in Db  query example, but in this situation there is a indexes problem